# Подскажите пожалуйста, как удалить из вложенного словаря те ключи и значения, которые больше переменной?

Tags: python, словари

Нужно было написать фу-ю, в которую передается вложенный словарь и опциональная переменная. Мне нужно удалить только те ключи и значения словаря, которые больше этой опциональной переменной.

```
    new = dict()

    all_departments = {
'development': {'Egor': 120000, 'Matvey': 175000, 'Juliana': 80000, 'Petr': 20000.5},
'system_administration': {'Danil': 96000.6, 'Diana':50000, 'Ivan': 15000.7, 'Anastasia': 23000.3},
'information_security': {'Alex': 30000.1, 'Asia': 110000.8, 'Daniil': 15000.4, 'Jacqueline': 126000.9}, 
'support_specialist': {'Artem': 49800.6, 'Sergei': 67839, 'Maria': 51078.7},
'hr': {'Ekaterina': 79456.9, 'Rima': 34256, 'Boris': 109674.3, 'Vladimir': 9810.52},
'accounting': {'Rina': 56734.9, 'Oleg': 87350, 'Konastantin': 27459.96}
    }

    def top_departments(all_departments: dict, salary_limit: float = None) -> dict:
        if salary_limit:
            for department, employee in all_departments.items():
                salary = employee.values() 
                if salary > salary_limit:
                all_departments.pop(employee)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
all_departments = {
'development': {'Egor': 120000, 'Matvey': 175000, 'Juliana': 80000, 'Petr': 20000.5},
'system_administration': {'Danil': 96000.6, 'Diana':50000, 'Ivan': 15000.7, 'Anastasia': 23000.3},
'information_security': {'Alex': 30000.1, 'Asia': 110000.8, 'Daniil': 15000.4, 'Jacqueline': 126000.9},
'support_specialist': {'Artem': 49800.6, 'Sergei': 67839, 'Maria': 51078.7},
'hr': {'Ekaterina': 79456.9, 'Rima': 34256, 'Boris': 109674.3, 'Vladimir': 9810.52},
'accounting': {'Rina': 56734.9, 'Oleg': 87350, 'Konastantin': 27459.96}
    }

def top_departments(all_departments: dict, salary_limit: float = float('inf')) -> dict:

    allres={}
    for kl,eld in all_departments.items():
        res = {}
        for k,z in eld.items():
            if z<salary_limit:
                res[k]=z
        if res:
            allres[kl]=res
    return allres




print(top_departments(all_departments))
```

---

```
{'development': {'Juliana': 80000, 'Petr': 20000.5}, 'system_administration': {'Diana': 50000, 'Ivan': 15000.7, 'Anastasia': 23000.3}, 'information_security': {'Alex': 30000.1, 'Daniil': 15000.4}, 'support_specialist': {'Artem': 49800.6, 'Sergei': 67839, 'Maria': 51078.7}, 'hr': {'Ekaterina': 79456.9, 'Rima': 34256, 'Vladimir': 9810.52}, 'accounting': {'Rina': 56734.9, 'Oleg': 87350, 'Konastantin': 27459.96}}
```

Comment: Спасибо, согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Перебираем ключи и значения внутренних словарей  и удаляем их, если значение больше переменной:

```
def top_departments(all_departments: dict, salary_limit: float = None) -> dict:
    if salary_limit is not None:
        for department, employees in all_departments.items():
            employees_to_remove = []
            for employee, salary in employees.items():
                if salary > salary_limit:
                    employees_to_remove.append(employee)
            for employee in employees_to_remove:
                del employees[employee]
    return all_departments
```